# Key listener only works when the Enter key is pressed. Doesn't work for other keys

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, javax

This code works fine when I press "Enter", but not when I press other keys. I added a key event in editable `JComboBox` which works only when the "Enter" key is pressed. I also want to add an event to another key.

```
comboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        int keyChar = e.getKeyChar();
        if (keyChar == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            textField.requestFocus();
        }    
        if (keyChar == KeyEvent.VK_TAB) { // tried other key also such as shift,alt,decimal...  
            textField_2.requestFocus();
        }        
    }
});
```

Comment: can you please provide a working SSCEE http://sscce.org

Answer (score 0):

Certain keys like TAB, which are used for focus events (e.g. tabbing from component to component) are already being consumed by the focus subsystem, which is why you are not seeing them on your key listener. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html. Read the part labeled **Version Note**. The article also offers alternatives on what you can do to capture TAB and other focus keys.